# get latitude,longitude and insert url

Tags: android, url, latitude-longitude

[image]i got the latitude and longitude use Location.
and save in

```
private double mLatitude;

private double mLongitude;.

mLatitude = location.getLatitude();

mLongitude =location.getLongitude();

locationMg =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

    String bestProvider = locationMg.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationMg.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    if(location != null){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Latitude" +location.getLatitude()+"\n"+"Longitude"+location.getLongitude(), 0).show();
         mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
         mLongitude = location.getLongitude();


    }
```

and

```
private String url ="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+mLatitude+"&lon="+mLongitude+"&mode=xml";
```

I saw LogCat After running this code .
However, the value of the longitude and latitude of 0.0 came out.
Why is it?
Is it because the string type url??????????????
and Latitude and longitude should only type is double.
Do change the url?

help.
I do not know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid location? How you are getting the Location Object?

Comment: Do you use emulator to test  this?

Comment: @keerthanamurugesan is right, test on real device...

Comment: @keerthanamurugesan no emulator,  google phone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you are not defining url after location is known. Put ir here:

```
if(location != null){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Latitude" +location.getLatitude()+"\n"+"Longitude"+location.getLongitude(), 0).show();
         mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
         mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
         url ="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+mLatitude+"&lon="+mLongitude+"&mode=xml";    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documention](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) 
`If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned from getLastKnownLocation()`

check whether location object is null.

Register for location updates using `requestLocationUpdates (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)`